# Prevent Cypress from maximizing/focusing browser window on test run

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cypress, microsoft-edge

Everything in the title: I need to run some Cypress test within browsers, not headless, as they use WebGL. But the fact that the new window is systematically focused for every spec file prevents me from running those tests in the background while I do something else.

I've found no options yet, either at Cypress level or at browser level to prevent this focus of the new window.

How could I prevent Cypress from focusing the test window? Is it even possible (focus might be needed to keep good performances for instance)?

Comment: If you want to run it in the background doesn`t headless run do the job with command npx cypress run

Comment: Hi, headless mode is not possible here, as headless mode will disable WebGL. I need to be able to screenshot the actual rendering, including WebGL.

Comment: Anyone knows Is there a solution to this problem after almost 3 years?